# Print bash arguments in reverse order

Tags: bash

I have to write a script, which will take all arguments and print them in reverse.

I've made a solution, but find it very bad. Do you have a smarter idea?

```
#!/bin/sh
> tekst.txt

for i in $* 
do
    echo $i | cat - tekst.txt > temp && mv temp tekst.txt
done

cat tekst.txt
```

Comment: You could add each to the front of a shell variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could do this

```
for (( i=$#;i>0;i-- ));do
        echo "${!i}"
done
```

This uses the below
[c style for loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for)
[Parameter indirect expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
(`${!i}`towards the bottom of the page)

And `$#` which is the number of arguments to the script

Comment: In *`ARITHMETIC EVALUATION`*  `i>0` is useless: u could: `for((i=$#;i;i--)){ echo "${!i}";}`

Comment: @F.Hauri It's not useless in arithmetic evaluation. In this particular case, sure you could use `i` on it's own, but only because 0 evaluates to false. Imagine you want every second param and there is an odd number. You will skip zero and cause a segfault

Answer (score 5):

you can use this one liner:

```
echo $@ | tr ' ' '\n' | tac | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Geat unless you have spaces in any of your arguments

Comment: will also break if you have glob characters in your arguments; will also break consecutive spaces; a better (and shorter and more efficient) method: `printf '%s\n' "$@" | tac`. Though, this will also break if you have newlines in your arguments.

Answer (score 2):

bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$@"; do
    echo "$i"
done | tac
```

call this script like:

```
./reverse 1 2 3 4
```

it will print:

```
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: Will break if arguments contain newlines. A shorter way is: `printf '%s\n' "$@" | tac`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I finally have it: [bash `reverse` function, without fork and without loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32647542/1765658). The only `eval` use a limited predefined string.

Answer (score 0):

Portably and POSIXly, without arrays and working with spaces and newlines:

Reverse the positional parameters:

```
flag=''; c=1; for a in "$@"; do set -- "$a" ${flag-"$@"}; unset flag; done
```

Print them:

```
printf '<%s>' "$@"; echo
```